# Can't grab a frame within an iframe and a frameset with javascript (domains are the same)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm tying to grab with javascript a HTML element located in a frame nested in an iframe and a frameset. The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<iframe id="central_iframe" name="central_iframe" (...)>
    <frameset cols="185, *" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
        <frame src="/subdomain" name="SideFrame" id="SideFrame" (...)>
```

Previously I've done it like this:

```
myIframe = document.getElementById('central_iframe');
mySideFrame = myIframe.contentDocument.getElementById('SideFrame');
myElement = mySideFrame.contentDocument.getElementById('iWantToGrabThis');
```

This however does not work here because myIframe.contentDocument returns null. myIframe.contentWindow on the other hand returns a window that has no properties at all (and hence myIframe.contentWindow.document is undefined). Similarly, when I try

```
central_iframe.SideFrame
```

also a window with no properties whatsoever is returned.

EDIT: The page is not mine and therefore I can't change its source. I'm just trying to interact with it.

I'm doing the testing in Chrome developer tools. I've also tried it with the same result in GeckoFX. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would be shocked if this is possible. Anti-XSS security features should prevent this in modern browsers.

Comment: @JustinMorgan I was under the impression it is blocked only if the domains from which the frames originate and the main page are different. Then again I know about this only as much as I've read on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research it indeed seems that Justin Morgan's suggestion is right and what I want is impossible. I made a partial workaround by loading the parent iframe in the browser to begin with. This allowed me to access the child frame (SideFrame) normally.

Answer (score 0):

an iframe points to an other source with the `src` attribute! you cant embed any html within an iframe. Put the frameset into a html file where you point to by the iframe src. You'll then be able to select the iframe from a script with `window.parent`. You can access the frames of the frameset with `document.frames`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have access to the page's source. I'm only trying to interact with it.